# How good are the predictions relative to the true values?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
import pickle

def compare_pred_with_true_values(weights):
    for vect in weights:
        if vect[1] <= 0.5:
            vect[1] = 0
        else:
            vect[1] = 1
    return weights

def counter(weights): 
    count_0_knowing_0 = 0
    count_1_knowing_1 = 0
    count_0_knowing_1 = 0
    count_1_knowing_0 = 0

    for vect in weights:
        if int(vect[0])==0 and vect[0]==vect[1]:
            count_0_knowing_0 += 1
        elif int(vect[0])==1 and vect[0]==vect[1]:
            count_1_knowing_1 += 1
        elif int(vect[0])==1 and vect[0]!=vect[1]:
            count_0_knowing_1 += 1
        else: 
            count_1_knowing_0 +=1

    json = {"count_0_knowing_0": count_0_knowing_0,
            "count_1_knowing_1": count_1_knowing_1,
            "count_0_knowing_1": count_0_knowing_1,
            "count_1_knowing_0": count_1_knowing_0}
    return json


if __name__ == "__main__":
    weights = pickle.load(open("weights_extension.pkl", "rb"))
    weights = [[vect[0], vect[1]] for vect in weights]

    weights_copy = compare_pred_with_true_values(weights)
    json = counter(weights_copy)
    print(json)
```

`weights` is simply a list of the form `[[0, 0.0013], [1, 0.578], ..., [0, 0.0012]]` and the output are `{"count_0_knowing_0": 4283, "count_1_knowing_1": 39717, "count_0_knowing_1": 1283, "count_1_knowing_0": 320}` The code is used to see "How good are the predictions relative to the true values?"

The code was for testing at the begin, but now I need to insert that inside my main code, but it is far from being optimal. I don't know if we can find a python lib that can do the same job. With Scikit-learn or scipy?

How can we extend that code so that it can work with more than one type of labels? Here is worked with the labels 0 and 1, but can we extend it so that it can work with the labels `{-n, .., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., m}`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to concise it. Any repetition can always* be removed. Where are you confused?               *in this case

Answer (score 0):

The `counter()` function can be wrote like this:

At the start, create the `json` variable like this:

```
json = {'count_{!s}_knowing_{!s}'.format(a, b): 0
        for a in range(2) for b in range(2)}
```

Then, references to variables like this:

```
count_0_knowing_0
```

becomes...

```
 json['count_0_knowing_0']
```

Then at the end just `return json` without creating the json variable again.